# Why is my arrays program showing null?

Tags: java, arrays, standard-deviation

My partner and I are trying to create an array program that separates the first and last name of the array and displays the blood pressure as well as the max, min, SD, and AVG  blood pressure. This is our program:

```
package arrays;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Arrays{
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  static double[] BP = {103, 111, 90, 72, 143, 144, 77, 88, 103};
  static double max = BP[0];
  static double min = BP[0];
  static double sd=0;
  static double avg=0;
  static double squareDiff=0;
  static double variance=0;
  static double calculation=0;
  static int i;
  static String item;
  static String[] pname= {"Jimmy Jones", "John Tod", "Tim Smith", "Mary Smith", "Sally Fields", "Smita Parval", "Sukhen Dey", "Jimmy Chang", "JoAnn Todler"};
  static String pfnameArray [] = new String[pname.length];
  static String plnameArray [] = new String[pname.length];
  static String pfname="";
  static String plname= "";
public static void Separate_names() {

for (int i = 0; i < pname.length; i++) {

    if(pname[i].substring(i, i+1).equals(' ')) {
    pfnameArray[i] = pname[i].substring(0, i);
    plnameArray[i] = pname[i].substring(i+1, pname.length+1);
    pfname = pfnameArray[i];
    plnameArray[i]=plname;
}
}
}
public static void Data_Entry() { 
  for (int i = 0; i < BP.length; i++) {
for (int i = 0; i< BP.length; i++) {
     if (BP[i] < min) min = BP[i];
  }
for(int a=0; a<BP.length; a++){
  calculation +=BP[a];
 }


avg=calculation/BP.length;
for(int v=0; v<BP.length; v++){
squareDiff+= Math.pow((BP[v]-avg),2);
variance=squareDiff/BP.length;
}
{sd =Math.sqrt(variance);
} 
}
public static void Print_Data(String [] fName, String [] lName) {
for( int l=0; l<BP.length; l++){

    System.out.println(plnameArray[i] + " " + pfnameArray[i] + ", Blood Pressure: " + BP[l]);
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Max is " + max);  
System.out.println("Min is " + min);
System.out.println ("Average is " + avg);
System.out.println("Standard Deviation:" + sd);

}}
```

For the output of the first and last name it is showing null. How do I separate the Array to where it doesn't show null? Also, is the formula for SD correct? We compared it with someone else's and got a different number.

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace? And what does "separate the Array to where it doesn't show null" mean? What are you trying to separate?

Comment: Also, the loop in `Separate_names` is all wrong, I think. It should be two nested loops, unless you are just looking for names whose first name length matches their index in the array, which I can't imagine is what you're actually looking for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what a stacktrace is (I'm a first year programming student with no prior experience). And I'm trying to separate the first and last name in the array pname and have them print last name then first name

Comment: I know the loop is wrong. We can't figure out how to make a nested loop.

Comment: OK, your problem is in the `Separate_names` method. I'll post a solution below.

Comment: Somebody beat me to it. I think the key point you're missing is that nested loops don't usually share a loop variable (they often do, but not in the way you're using them). So for example, in your `Data_Entry` method, you have a loop inside a loop where both of them use the variable `i`.  Change the inner one to `j` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` like this:

```
pfnameArray[] = pname[i].split(" ");
```

`pfnameArray[0]` will contain the first name
`pfnameArray[1`] will contain the lase name

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: Whenever I use the solution you gave me, a red error sign shows up (we are using netbeans) and my program does not run.